# echo: write error: Operation not permitted

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

Running as root user yet I'm still not permitted to use this:

```
echo "21" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/direction
echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/value
```

Comment: Could you cut and paste the system prompt, what you type in, and the system's response?

Comment: I was able to get it to work after leaving it off for a few hours not sure why that would cause a change however

Answer (score 3):

1) Check you are root:

```
id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1001(indiecity)
```

2) Use more robust code to avoid typos, state conflicts etc:

```
pinon() {
    N=$1
    if [ ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio$N ] ; then
        echo "$N" > /sys/class/gpio/export
    fi
    echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$N/direction
    echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$N/value
}

pinon 21
```

3) Help us Help you by copy pasting the exact error message and the output of a few verification tests:

```
file /sys/class/gpio/gpio21
/sys/class/gpio/gpio21: ERROR: cannot open `/sys/class/gpio/gpio21' (No such file or directory)
```

etc, if you **edit your question** to make it more answerable people will up-vote instead of down-vote it.

4) Although you are not able to reproduce this issue please select an answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo su
echo 21 > /sys/class/gpio/export
cd /sys/class/gpio/gpio21
echo out > direction
echo 0 > value
```

Comment: You should expand on your answer and explain why this will work and how it differs from what the OP did.

Comment: Your post is the same as the OPs example, likely the OP tried double exporting, try offering a more robust solution.